# Log mode of short X-axis pfgplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to obtain this graph (made in Origin):

[image]

Both axes in log scale.

This is MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    ymode=log,
    xmode=log,
    log ticks with fixed point
    ]
\addplot table {
9   1.75439
14  0.71429
18  0.41667
19  0.33333
34  0.11765
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The x-axis looks awful. What is the way to make it look like in Origin?

Comment: Add `xtick={10,15,...,35}` and I have to say Origin is not pretty either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to define your x-ticks interval manually.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        ,ymode=log
        ,xmode=log
        ,log ticks with fixed point
        ,xtick={10,15,...,35}
        ,minor xtick={1,...,40}
    ]
    \addplot table {
        9   1.75439
        14  0.71429
        18  0.41667
        19  0.33333
        34  0.11765
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But what about extra-ticks between values?

Comment: `minor xtick={10,...,35}`